# Unexpected symbol error, R programming, new learner

Tags: r

```
myfunction <- function(y){
     y <- rnorm(100)
     mean(y) 

}

myfunction()
[1] 0.05248908
dir()
[1] "myfunction.R"
source("myfunction.R")
```

> Error in source("myfunction.R") : myfunction.R:2:3: unexpected symbol
>    1: 
>    2: R version

I just started learning R programming. I couldn't find an answer to this error.

Comment: The problem could be reproduced until the code was (wrongly) edited by Marco Sandri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting your code like this:

```
myfunction <- function() {
  y <- rnorm(100)
  mean(y)
}
```

Should work then.

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thank you!
So, there shouldn't be any variable in the function() thing ever?

Comment: The argument list of your function is empty because your function has no argument; `y` is assigned within the function.

Comment: Alright, thank you! :)